# Error when calling object constructor

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to create a new blob object:

```
function Blob(X,Y,R) {
this.x = X;
this.y = Y;
this.r = R;

this.show = function (ctx) {
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fill();
}

this.moveTo = function(x,y,ctx){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff"
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fill();
}

    var myBlob = new Blob(250,250,50);
    blob.show(ctx);
```

When I create the object I get an error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties.

Comment: This isn’t how `Blob` works. Read the docs carefully.

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to create an actual Blob: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob? If so, those arguments are incorrect, and I'm pretty sure you're not trying to do that anyway.

Comment: well sry guys JUST IMAGINE BLOB would be circle or so

Comment: just nameb my class blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the full code.

With what you have there, you don't have a class named Blob. Nor do you have a function called show.

Maybe take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes for more information.

```
class BlobClass {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.r = r;
  }

  get show() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff"
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

const blob = new BlobClass(10, 10, 10);

blob.show()
```

This should do what I think you're trying to do. You probably shoulden't name the class Blob, because that is the name of a buildt in feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but as the error message says your passing the wrong arguments when creating the blob. For example you could pass a list, so a blob would be created:

```
var myBlob = new Blob([250,250,50]);
```

But please provide more details.